# How to achieve optional URL components with mod_rewrite RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have  `set.php?mod=avatar` `set.php?mod=info`. Now I want make it set/mod this, using this:

```
RewriteRule ^set/(.*)/?$ set.php?mod=$1
```

It's working, but when open it like `set/`, it's give me 404 error. How can I make it in one pharse?

Like:

```
RewriteRule ^set/if this exist ok if not I want it equal set.php only(.*)/?$ set.php?mod=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
RewriteRule ^set/([^/]+)/?$ set.php?mod=$1
```